# Groupby consecutive elements in pandas series with same key

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have a Series in DataFrame which contains only 0 or 1. I want to get the list of lengths of each 'cluster' of 0. Here is a toy model:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,0,0,1,0]})
```

What I expect is `[2,1]`

To do that I could the following:

```
a[a['x']==0].index
```

and then use groupby for looking for consecutive indexes as already learned on SO. By the way is there a more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this result using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
grouper = (list(s) for _, s in groupby(data))
lengths = [len(s) for s in grouper if s[0] == 0]
print(lengths)
```

Not sure if `groupby` in `pandas` is coded the same.